# Joining Multiple table with Regex

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join multiple tables that end with `_game_type`.

My currently method is to loop through a list of game types and create join statements.

I'm wondering if I can use regex on the table names to join the tables with the same ending instead.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So, you don't know the table names ahead of time?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I do, but just wondering if it can be done with regex.

Comment: The only way to dynamically choose tables to join (or include in any query really) is by assembling the query string with code.